# Android: Correct dimension values for Nexus 5 and Pixel 3a

Tags: android

I have a project where I store dimens in
`values`, `values-sw320dp`, `values-sw400dp` and so on.

It works great for most part except when 2 devices have same `sw` values but different ppi.

e.g. Nexus 5 and Pixel 3a both accept dimens from `values-sw320dp-xxhdpi`. However, Pixel3a obviously has more pixel so it can take bigger dimens value.

However, I am not sure how to split it up further so that both devices refer to different dimens. I have read up online as and on SO as well but I couldn't find any references for cases like above.

Appreciate any thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: The whole point of `dp` is that they are density independent pixels - i.e., the same physical size. Is there a reason you're concerned about a differing ppi or working in pixels directly?

Comment: I am trying to get correct dimen value for height and width for an image/card view for different dp sizes but these 2 accept dimens from same dp folders which is a cause of concern

Comment: The dp size will be the same, that's kind of the entire point of using dp.

Comment: I understand that. I am saying how can I differentiate and create another `values-swxxxdp` folder so that they both pick different values

Comment: May be there's a gap in my understanding of using sw-dp folders. Maybe I need to use dimens different way which I am not sure. What I am trying to say is for e.g. 160dp dimen looks correct on Pixel 3a but doesn't on Nexus 5. I am trying to figure out a way so that one device selects let's say 144 dp and other does 160 dp. I hope that makes sense